# Locating an image file in a pyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, helper

I am writing a simple game with pyGame.

Structure-wise, I have separated my game into several files:

- main.py `# the main runner, it loads up the environment`
- class_tank.py `# it defines the player-controlled tank class`
- class_shell.py `# it defines the shells that shoot from the player's tank`
- class_mob.py `# it defines the enemies`

The relationship of the modules above is:

- `main.py` imports `class_tank.py`, `class_shell.py` and `class_mob.py`
- all of `class_tank.py`, `class_shell.py` and `class_mob.py` are subclasses of `pygame.Sprite.sprite`.

Currently, I noticed that I am repeating myself by having the following code snippets in all four files:

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'Resources')
img_folder_path = os.path.join(resource_path, 'Images')
bg_img_path = os.path.join(img_folder_path, "xxxx.png")
```

`xxxx.png` is the image I need to load for the background (main.py), for the player (class_tank.py), for bullets (class_shell.py) and for enemies (class_mob.py).

Logically, this code snippet does belong to each of the file, but is there any elegant way to not repeat myself? The only way I can think of is to define an additional `helper` class.

Comment: What is the class hierarchy (if any) in your program?  Which files import which other files?  Without more context, we can’t give you a very good answer.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, thanks. I added more info to my post.

Comment: I want to answer your question, but as it currently stands, without actual code, it is not really a "Code Review" question.  There are several ways to avoid repeating yourself.  1) Your "helper" class.  2) An `Entity` class that derives from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, with an image load method, that your other classes derive from.  3) Dependency injection; your main module could load all images and inject them into each `class`.  Or combinations of the above.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, thank you so much. I did not know anything about dependency injection, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need classes in Python. The `helper` class approach is the same direction as I would go, just with a plain module.
Basically, your `resource_path` and `img_folder_path` are constants, so I would simply create a module `constants.py` with the following:

```
import os

RESOURCE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__), 'Resources')
IMG_FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join(resource_path, 'Images')
```

You can then simply import `constants.py` everywhere you need to know those paths.